# fabric - $(env_name) not getting set

Tags: fabric

I would like to create env variables once to use elsewhere in my fabric file.  For example:

```
from fabric.api import *

# environments
def dtconfig():
    env.path = 'David'
# tasks
def hello():
    require('path', provided_by=[dtconfig])
    print (env.path)
    print ('Hello $(path)')
    print ('Hello ' + env.path)
```

The output from running 'fab dtconfig hello' is:

```
David
Hello $(path)
Hello David
```

Why doesn't the $(path) get replaced with 'David'?  thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like bash variables were removed in later versions of fabric.  just used plain old %s string substitutions instead.